# How to set onclick event with JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a popup on map pin click, where the user clicks on a link which initiates a function call. Here's the call that creates the pin

```
new mapboxgl.Marker(el)
            .setLngLat(marker.geometry.coordinates)
            .setPopup(new mapboxgl.Popup({offset: 25}) // add popups
                .setHTML(popup(marker.properties)))
            .addTo(map);
```

And here's the popup function

```
function popup(properties) {
    return '<div>' +
        '<h3>' + properties.partnerName + '</h3>' +
        '<a onclick="mapPinSelect()">' + 'Link' + '</a>' +
        '</div>';
}
```

Everything works fine, but when I convert my popup method to JQuery, my `onClick` method stops working.
Here's the JQuery version

```
function popup(properties) {
    return $('<div>')
            .append($('<h3>').append(properties.partnerName))
            .append($('<a>').click(mapPinSelect).append('Link'))
            .html()
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are not attaching your click handler to the link, but to the div. Like all chaining methods, `.append` still returns the jQuery object you called it _on_, not the element you just appended.

Comment: One mistake is you have to pass a function as parameter in the click function. So .click(mapPinSelect())

Comment: Plus, I am not sure if an event handler attached using `.click()` survives the HTML serialization.

Comment: Or you can add an attribute onclick with jQuery as well to have the same functionality

Comment: Try to attach the handler using "on" (https://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: You should return the element instead of its html result.

Answer (score 0):

You should use "on", that should work for dynamically created elements.

```
$("div#container").on('click', 'button.alert', function() {
    alert(1);
});
```

https://api.jquery.com/on/
[Difference between .on('click') vs .click()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9122078/difference-between-onclick-vs-click)